# OpenCV Python cv2.mixChannels()

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to convert this from C++ to Python, but it is giving different hue results.

In C++:

```
/// Transform it to HSV
cvtColor( src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV );

/// Use only the Hue value
hue.create( hsv.size(), hsv.depth() );
int ch[] = { 0, 0 };
mixChannels( &hsv, 1, &hue, 1, ch, 1 );
```

I tried this in Python:

```
# Transform it to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Use only the Hue value
hue = np.zeros(hsv.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
ch = [0] * 2
cv2.mixChannels(hsv, hue, ch)
```

Comment: Can you post the results from both programs so we can have a better idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Similarly to how the C++ code takes arrays of Mats for the source and destination, you need to feed it lists in Python: `cv2.mixChannels([hsv], [hue], [0,0])`

Comment: It worked @DanMašek !, I changed the last line to cv2.mixChannels([hsv], [hue], ch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you look in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels), you can see the C++ functions taking as arguments arrays (or vectors) of `Mat` as input and output.

> `C++: void mixChannels(const Mat* src, size_t nsrcs, Mat* dst, size_t ndsts, const int* fromTo, size_t npairs)`
>
> `C++: void mixChannels(const vector<Mat>& src, vector<Mat>& dst, const int* fromTo, size_t npairs)`

Similarly, in Python you need to provide lists of `np.array` for both source and destination.

### Code Sample

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('cage.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Baseline for comparison
h,_,_ = cv2.split(hsv)

hue = np.zeros(hsv.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.mixChannels([hsv], [hue], [0,0])

print np.array_equal(h, hue[:,:,0])
```

### Console Output

```
>python mix.py
True
```