# Detecting Squares OpencCV with Python3.5

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am beginner with OpenCV, and I must detect squares of a photo, but, I have an or some errors. Do you know if anyone could help me?

The image that I am using is this:

[image]

And I am trying to finds squares to image,however. I cannot do very well. I think, the error is that I need matrix in format CV_8UC1, but I do not know how can get it.

```
def findSquaresInImage(image):
    blurred = np.mat(image.shape,np.dtype('u8'))
    blurred = cv2.blur(blurred, (5, 5))
    cv2.medianBlur(image, 9, blurred)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray0 = np.mat(blurred.copy(), np.dtype('u8'))
    gray = np.mat(image.shape,np.dtype("u8"))
    # ret, gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    squares = []
    contours = []
    for c in range(3):
       ch = [c, 0]

       image = cv2.mixChannels(blurred,gray0,ch)

       threshold_level = 2
    for l in range(threshold_level):
        if l == 0:

            cv2.Canny(gray0, 10, 20, gray,3)

            cv2.dilate(gray, np.array([]), gray, (-1, -1))
        else:
            gray = gray0 >= (l+1) * 255 / threshold_level

        (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(gray.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 ....
```

A main routine that I am using, you might change the directory and the name of the image to run the file:

```
name = "./directory/file"
image = cv2.imread(name, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
image =findSquaresInImage(image)
```

Comment: can you upload the images you are working with?

Comment: Yes, I have attached the image in the question

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329901/opencv-python-cv2-mixchannels) useful to show the `dtype` parameter in use for creating matrices or arrays. Particularly `dtype=np.uint8` in the original poster's call to `np.zeros()` seems to be adaptable to what you're trying to do with `np.mat()` in your example.